# How do I draw a line in Visio 2010 without the end points jumping around?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

I am trying to draw lines in Visio 2010, but for a reason, the end (and for that matter the start) points keep jumping around. That is, if I want to draw small shapes, they can only be drawn in 0 and multiple of 45 degree angles. I figure it has to do with the "grid", but how can I turn that off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the View tab of the ribbon click on the box, bottom right, of the Visual Aids group.

This allows you to control what things Visio will snap your lines to.