# How do I draw a line in Visio 2007 without the end points jumping around?

Tags: microsoft-visio-2007

Im trying to a block diagram with some blocks nested within a top level box, the lower level boxes need to have multiple connections between them but Visio's auto connection feature is hindering that, another problem is that the tool will only let me draw a line with no more then one right angle.

Is there a way to turn off the auto-connect feature?

Related (Same problem but with Visio 2010): [How do I draw a line in Visio 2010 without the end points jumping around?](https://superuser.com/q/178116/38551)

Comment: I do not think that your issue with things jumping around is related to the post that you cited. That has to do with placing objects, and should have nothing to do with connectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tools -> Options -> General -> Drawing Window` There is a check box there called enable autoconnect. Uncheck it.

With regard to the one right angle allowed, just change the connector style right clicking on the connector, and changing the style to curved.

**Edit:** If you are actually talking about lines, and would just like a visio 2007 way to do what the answer did in visio 2010, go to `Tool -> Snap and Glue -> General -> Currently Active` uncheck snap.

Comment: Thanks your first suggestion helped, although its still not directly possible to draw a line on top of a box; I first have to draw the line outside of the box and then drag it in.. and to draw lines with multiple angles I need to draw multiple lines and join them  by draging them... frustrating!

Answer (score -2):

I found line without connectors - Line-curve connector. In format you can add arrow to one of ends and get arrow without connectors to shapes